# how to remove <textarea> whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a `<textarea>`, as the one I'm writing in right now actually.

How do I make the textarea behave like this one? I want it to start at the beginning and not give me whitespace to erase when clicking in the middle of it.

**HTML**

```
      <p>
        <textarea class="noteToAdd">

        </textarea>
      </p>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML / CSS to your question

Comment: @Simplicity I added the relevant code, It's nothing special though because I don't know how to do this yet.

Comment: 1. create it without whitespace: `<textarea class="noteToAdd"></textarea>`; 2. $(function() { $(".noteToAdd").val("");});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That what is between the start tag `<textarea>` and end tag `</textarea>` is it's value. Even whitespace is seen as 'value'. You probably have something like this: (note the whitespace)

```html
<textarea>
            
</textarea>
```

So, to remove that, remove all whitespace and place the start and ending tag directly after each other.

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your whitespace between the `textarea` tag. Like as

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Try this one :

```html
<p>
  <textarea class="noteToAdd">    
  </textarea>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no whitespace between your `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags, any whitespace here will show up in your text area.

More help is not possible without you providing the HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra white space in between the `textarea opening and closing tags` as they take up that space. You write your content inside `<textarea></textarea>`

```html
<p>
  <textarea class="noteToAdd"></textarea>
</p>
```